# Application won't quit from dock icon, quits qt instead

Tags: macos, qt, acrobat

I'm using Qt in an application's plugin. Since upgrading Qt from 4.3.4 to 4.6.4 carbon, Qt seems to want to take control of the application. To regain the menu, I have done

qApp->setAttribute(Qt::AA_MacPluginApplication,true);

However, when I try to close the application from the dock icon, Qt quits instead of the application.

How can that be corrected?

Additional infos:
- Show/Hide from dock works as expected.
- ⌘Q quits the native application (as expected)
- Quit from the menu quits the native application (as expected)
- Same problem with Qt 4.6.4 cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Qt bug introduced in 4.6.
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-8087?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Fortunately, there is workaround.

```
long refCon = 0;
AEEventHandlerUPP handler = NULL;
AEGetEventHandler(kCoreEventClass, kAEQuitApplication, &handler, &refCon, false);

QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_MacPluginApplication, true);
int argc = 0;
(void)new QApplication(argc, 0, true);

if (handler)
{
    AEInstallEventHandler(kCoreEventClass, kAEQuitApplication, handler, refCon, false);
}
```